# Datamapper one-to-one association (has 1) issue

Tags: ruby, datamapper, ruby-datamapper

I am using datamapper in association with postgres

I have 2 classes defined like this:

```
class Dep
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial
  has 1, :rec, 'Rec'
end 

class Rec
  include DataMapper::Resource  

  property :id, Serial
  belongs_to :dep, 'Dep'

end
```

When I try to do so and access the dep model I get an error:
    undefined method 'rec_id' for #

As far as my research goes the model that is created does not have a one to one relationship. Instead it has a one to many relationship. I think that is the problem.
Is there any way to create a one to one relationship in datamapper?

Further, it does not let me use :required => false with 'has 1'

Using belongs_to both side does not create a proper relationship. It creates to relationships instead which is undesirable.
Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Did you definitely call `DataMapper.finalize` ?

Comment: Yes i did. And it works fine with has n. Only has 1 seems to have a problem

Comment: Please edit the question to include an example showing how you're using this. `rec_id` should not exist anywhere. `Rec` should have a `dep_id` (as this is how `has 1` works).

Comment: Note that you can use a `belongs_to` on both sides of the join.

Comment: Using belongs_to on both the sides does not create an inverse relationship which means that two separate relationships will be made which is not desirable as I already mentioned. I am not using rec_id anywhere. I have an application which has ember on the front end which queries for required records to the datamapper. So, when in ember I query any dep record I get the above error. I have tried it using rake console as well to ensure its not an ember side problem and I get the same error.